# Suppose $\gamma$ is the root of some irred. polynomial in F[x], why is [F($\gamma$):F($\gamma^3$)] $\leq$ 3

Tags: field-theory

I have verified the inequality for a concrete case, but I'm not sure how to show that it is generally true.  How can this be proven?  Also, if we replace 3 by some other number, will analogous inequalities hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of $F(\gamma)$ will be a $F$-linear combination of an element of $F(\gamma^3)$, with another element of $\gamma F(\gamma^3)$ and, finally, with another element of $\gamma^2 F(\gamma^3)$. And, yes, you can generalize.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \geq 1$. Can you find a polynomial $f(x) \in F(\gamma^n)[x]$ of degree $n$ satisfied by $\gamma$? If so, then the minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $F(\gamma^n)$ has degree at most $n$, hence $[F(\gamma) : F(\gamma^n)] \leq n$.